# Display beacons and People in an Indoor Location

Tags: android, sdk, beacon, proximity

I want to create an application which display all the beacons around an Indoor space along with their range radius, and track people moving around with mobile devices. I have viewed various SDK: Radius, ALTBeacon, Google Eddystone Api and none of gives this feature. Also how to make the map for the indoor area.

Just want a guide in what way to proceed. As none of the sdk has full functionality

Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ATgy4_8IY

Comment: your question is way too broad. In general - no SDKs will provide you with the location of other people. You need to implement it by yourself. Each device has to determine it's location based on beacons, and send it to the server, where the other device will pick it up and show.

Comment: I want to make something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ATgy4_8IY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you need to do this is an indoor Location SDK.  Such SDKs are much more specialized than a general purpose beacon SDK as beacons do not by themselves give you an X/Y location.  These kinds of positioning systems are difficult to set up, and generally require payment for use.  You might try the Estimote Indoor Location SDK.

Once you have this, you must produce your own map (by drawing it yourself or using a scanned copy of an existing floor plan.). You then simply edit your map in an image editor to mark the location of the beacons (or plot them programmatically).

The above is all possible but requres  a lot of work.  The detailed steps are far more numerous than can be answered in a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you think https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/ this library will work well for this application ?

Comment: No, unless you build an Indoor Location system yourself using the library (no easy task).  The library tells you what beacons it sees with a rough distance estimate, but will not give you an x,y coordinate of the user's position in the indoor space.

Comment: I managed to obtain the X,Y coordinates of the user, i just need a little more help to plot the beacons and the user location somewhere on an Indoor Layout, there is no navigation required just normal visualization. 
So currently i have the X,Y coordinates of all beacons which are not exactly lat long but some random values like (0,0) (1,1) etc. And i am finding the distance using altbeacon library from the nearest beacons and calculating the centroid and also getting a X,Y coordinate. Do help to build a UI representation of beacons and the person on an indoor map layout.